# golang mongodb how to reload session

Tags: mongodb, go

- txn and txn1 are transaction based crud methods,
- If after txn, session1 and sessionContext objects are lost, only sessionID and mongo.client are not lost, how to reload session
- Use mongodb sharding cluster, three mongos

```
.....

func main(){
    ......
    sessionOpts := &options.SessionOptions{}
    sessionOpts.SetDefaultWriteConcern(wc).SetDefaultReadConcern(rc).SetDefaultMaxCommitTime(&maxCommitTime)

    session1, _ := client.StartSession(sessionOpts)
    sessionContext := mongo.NewSessionContext(ctx, session1)
    if err := sessionContext.StartTransaction(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    txn(client, session1, sessionContext, ctx) // Transaction-based crud

    fmt.Println(session1.ID().String())
    // ???

    session2 := ?
    sessionContext2 := mongo.NewSessionContext(ctx, session2)

    txn1(client, session2, sessionContext2, ctx)    // Transaction-based crud
    defer sessionContext.EndSession(ctx)
    sessionContext.CommitTransaction(sessionContext)
    ......
}

func txn(client *mongo.Client, session1 mongo.Session, sessionContext mongo.SessionContext, ctx context.Context) {

    if _, err := client.Database(database).Collection(collection).InsertMany(sessionContext, students[0:1]); err != nil {
        if err := sessionContext.AbortTransaction(context.Background()); err != nil {
            logs.Error("mongo transaction rollback failed, %s", err.Error())
            panic(err)
        }
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

go.mod

```
go 1.16

require (
    github.com/beego/beego/v2 v2.0.4
    github.com/google/uuid v1.2.0
    go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.10.6
)
```

please help me out thanks

Comment: Isn’t this an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)?